# How to print json info with python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json (url = http://open.data.amsterdam.nl/ivv/parkeren/locaties.json) and I want to print all 'title', 'adres', 'postcode'. How can I do that?

I want to print it like this:

```
title.
adres.
postcode.

title. 
adres. 
postcode.
```

so among themselves

[image: this is my python script]

I hope you can help me with this

```html
import urllib, json
url = "http://open.data.amsterdam.nl/ivv/parkeren/locaties.json"
import requests
search = requests.get(url).json()
print(search['title'])
print(search['adres'])
print(search['postcode'])
```

Comment: show your code as text

Comment: share your code, not picture

Comment: i have done it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `print(json.dumps(r, indent=4))` you can see that the structure is

```
{
    "parkeerlocaties": [
        {
            "parkeerlocatie": {
                "title": "Fietsenstalling Tolhuisplein",
                "Locatie": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9032801,52.3824545]}",
                 ...
            }
        },
        {
            "parkeerlocatie": {
                "title": "Fietsenstalling Paradiso",
                "Locatie": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.8833735,52.3621851]}",
                 ...
            }
        },
```

So to access the inner properties, you need to follow the JSON path

```
import requests
url = ' http://open.data.amsterdam.nl/ivv/parkeren/locaties.json'
search = requests.get(url).json()
for parkeerlocatie in search["parkeerlocaties"]:
    content = parkeerlocatie['parkeerlocatie']
    print(content['title'])
    print(content['adres'])
    print(content['postcode'])
    print()
```